# What does a line like `apples: 5` do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript myself. There is a confusion with some javascript,

```
price = 14;
name = "Mary";
apples:5; //This line executing without error
"orranges":6; //This line getting error
alert(name);
```

Those both lines can be used into a json object without any error. But when I am using those lines outside of json object, 2nd line (**"orranges":6;**) is getting error. Why is that ? And why is not giving error for the first line (**apples:5;**), is there any way that I can use it outside of json object ?

Comment: Obligatory: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ .

Comment: Related and possibly duplicates: [`[javascript] colon`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+colon) . Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:` isn't an operator, it forms part of label syntax.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

> `label : 
> statement`
>   *label*
> Any JavaScript identifier that is not a reserved word.

`apples` is an identifier.

`"orranges"` is a string literal.

> is there any way that I can use it outside of json object ?

You seem to be confusing JSON with object literal syntax.

You can't use a `:` as the character that separates a property name from a value in an object when you aren't in the process of defining an object.